# Hide search google search bar on nexus 5

Tags: google-now, google-search

- Running slimkat modded rom 4.4.2
- I would like to keep full functionality of google now, but just hide the srarch bar from view on the home screen (clean screen, with no "say 'ok google' " on top of the wallpaper)
- Any help provided would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay ,so firstly I will help removing that Ok Google funcationality from the Home screen:

1.Go to Google Now > tap Settings  > Voice > "Ok Google" Hotword detection > here you will see an option to disable Ok Google on Home Screen.

Now for the search bar , if you are running SlimKat , then you are probably on one of the two custom launchers pre-installed in Slimkat , so go to their settings , either by long holding on homecreen , or you can go to Settings > Home > here you will see the launchers installed , and mostly there is a settings/options key beside them , tap on that or if settings key is not there try tapping on the launcher name ( it should take you to settings).

once in launcher settings , you should go to Homescreen specific settings and disable search bar from there.

Get back to me if any of the above mentioned things don't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help... I was able to turn off hot-word detection... But can't seem to be able to remove the search bar from homescreen... No launcher specific option to disable the search bar

Comment: Then i think u should switch to a launcher

Answer (score 2):

Try [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher). It has an option to disable persistent search bar.

Comment: On my Nexus 5x running Marshmallow, setting it to none still shows the default search bar; setting it to anything else shows two of them.